# Reference range of sections with a dash

Tags: cross-referencing

In my document, I reference a string of sections within a sentence. A representative example would be:

```
I am referencing Sections \ref{A}, \ref{B}, \ref{C}.
```

This then comes out t something like:

```
I am referencing Sections 6.1, 6.2, 6.3.
```

How can I get it to display:

```
I am referencing Sections 6.1-3
```

without hard-coding it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package you can compress a range and using `\crefstripprefix` (recent versions of the package), you can remove the common prefixes from reference range:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefrangelabelformat{section}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{5}
\chapter{Test chapter}

As we see in \cref{sec:testa,sec:testb,sec:testc}...

\section{Test section}
\label{sec:testa}
\section{Test section}
\label{sec:testc}
\section{Test section}
\label{sec:testb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\crefrangelabelformat` you can customize the format for a range of references. It has the syntax:

```
\crefrangelabelformat{<type>}{<format>}
```

The first argument specifies the `<type>` of references that will be customized; for the second argument, the `cleveref` documentation explains:

> The  argument should contain six arguments: `#1`, `#2`, `#3`, `#4`,
>   `#5`, `#6`. The first two (`#1` and `#2`) are the formatted versions of the two label counters defining the reference range. The next two (`#3` and
>   `#4`) denote the beginning and end of the hyperlink for the first reference, the final two (`#5` and `#6`), the hyperlink for the second
>   reference. The hyperlink arguments must appear in order.

`\crefstripprefix` simply removes the prefix (the chapter number, in this case) from the second part of the range.

Here's an enhanced example in which the prefix has been stripped out for cross-references to ranges of sections, subsections and equations:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefrangelabelformat{section}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
\crefrangelabelformat{subsection}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}{(#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6)}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{5}
\chapter{Test chapter}

As we see in \cref{sec:testa,sec:testb,sec:testc}...

As we see in \cref{ssec:testa,ssec:testb,ssec:testc}...

As we see in \cref{equ:testa,equ:testb,equ:testc}...

\section{Test section}
\begin{equation}
\label{equ:testa}
a = b.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{equ:testb}
a = b.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{equ:testc}
a = b.
\end{equation}
\label{sec:testa}
\section{Test section}
\label{sec:testc}
\subsection{Test ssubection}
\label{ssec:testa}
\subsection{Test ssubection}
\label{ssec:testb}
\subsection{Test ssubection}
\label{ssec:testc}
\section{Test section}
\label{sec:testb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Medina, this looks great! Can you please just explain a little more this line: \crefrangelabelformat{section}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

Comment: @user1357015 Of course. I've added a little explanation to my answer.

Comment: @Medina, ok, I'm still a bit confused and can't seem to get this to work. How would the example change if I wanted subsections 4.2.1-4.2.3 then? Perhaps with another example I would be able to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @user1357015 You need the most recent version of `cleveref` installed.

Comment: Texmaker just installed cleverref. I'm assuming it installed the latest version?

Comment: @user1357015 Sorry for the other comment; I wrote a comment for other user :) I'll add some more examples to my answer. The important thing is to have the latest version of `cleveref`.

Comment: just checked miktex, it's 0.19

Comment: @user1357015 then, it should work. In some seconds I'll add the enhanced example.

Comment: @user1357015 I've already added the new example.

Comment: Ok, I 've copied in: 

\crefrangelabelformat{subsection}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

and then put in: 

\cref{iPAC:new, iPAC:more, iPAC:less}. However I get:

 'presented in section 4.2.1 and ????'-- still doesn't work. Also, how do can I change "section" to "Sections" (capital).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12672/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-user1357015)

Comment: @user1357015 I provided a link to a chat room, so we can discuss further the issue. Simply follow the link in my previous comment.